# C# Web browser - How to click this button (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, c#, html, button

I went through many discussions and I wasted over 1 hour trying to do something with this. But I didn't find the solution.. so.. I have this html piece of code and I need to trigger that javascript thing I've red lined.. I tried to trigger it through chrome, it went with no probs when I put it in the console and entered..

I need to know, how to trigger this in c# web browser. (I am kinda new to programming, I never studied the HTML or javascript, I just can do small things in c# - so I don't know much about those elements etc)

I need to trigger this thing - javascript:Skylab.sendTransport('normal');

Any idea how ?

Screen with the code in colors: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLDjZ.png

```
<div id="transport_right">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="width:41px;"><img id="to_skylab" src="http://do-test.a.bpcdn.net/do_img/global/pilotSheet/skylab/to_skylab_0.png?__cv=1f08c141b032cd3f3800247fe3f58100" width="41" height="36"></td>
        <td style="width:23px;"><img id="but_to_skylab" src="http://do-test.a.bpcdn.net/do_img/global/pilotSheet/skylab/but_right_0.png?__cv=ac1391c5509c09a46cc9bd5e36c51400" width="17" height="17"></td>
        <td style="width:29px"><img id="to_ship" src="http://do-test.a.bpcdn.net/do_img/global/pilotSheet/skylab/to_ship_0.png?__cv=b76cfb40c24b488ac9f685627faad600" width="29" height="36"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" style="padding-top:20px;">
            <div class="button_standard">
                <a style="display:block" onfocus="this.blur()" href="javascript:Skylab.sendTransport('fast', 'Chceš tento transport skutečně zahájit?','OK','Storno');">ihned odeslat</a>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" style="padding-top:5px;"><strong>1187 U.</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" style="padding-top:25px;">
            <div class="button_standard">
                <a style="display:block" onfocus="this.blur()" href="javascript:Skylab.sendTransport('normal');">odeslat</a>
            </div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You want this on <a> click ?

Comment: TRY `<a style="display:block" onfocus="this.blur()"  href="#" onclick="Skylab.sendTransport('normal');">odeslat</a>`

Answer (score 1):

You should use the attribute OnClick instead of the href, and set the href to #:

```
<a style="display:block" onfocus="this.blur()" href="#" onclick="Skylab.sendTransport('normal');">odeslat</a>
```

Comment: I guess you want to trigger it on the client side, for that give an id to the anchor and call $( "#foo" ).trigger( "click" );

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand - as I said, I am still a newbie. 

I have c# web browser, how do I find this exactly and trigger it ? Could you show me on piece of the code ?

Comment: I need to know what you are trying to achieve. Can you explain what a c# web browser is? You mean, you have an web application?

Comment: I want my program to be able automatically do things in a browser game, so I am using "Web browser" in visual studio and its visible on my form. It's windows Forms Application.
And I need to programmatically click this button.. I have no idea how am I supposed to do my code. (It's mostly because I have no idea about html and javascript)

Comment: I am not familiar with browser object in windows forms, but in a web application you cannot trigger a client side button (that is your case) from the server side, the user has to press/click on the button in the browser to trigger it.